# How do I read any request header in PHP?

Tags: php, http-headers

How should I read any header in PHP?

For example the custom header: `X-Requested-With`.

Comment: "Any header" is ambiguous. You can't read "any header" in one operation, but you can read the incoming list of request headers and the current outgoing list of response headers separately.

Answer (score 475, accepted):

**IF**: you only need a single header, instead of *all* headers, the quickest method is:

```
<?php
// Replace XXXXXX_XXXX with the name of the header you need in UPPERCASE (and with '-' replaced by '_')
$headerStringValue = $_SERVER['HTTP_XXXXXX_XXXX'];
```

**ELSE IF**: you run PHP as an Apache module or, as of PHP 5.4, using FastCGI (simple method):

[apache_request_headers()](http://www.php.net/apache_request_headers)

```
<?php
$headers = apache_request_headers();

foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
    echo "$header: $value <br />\n";
}
```

**ELSE:** In any other case, you can use (userland implementation):

```
<?php
function getRequestHeaders() {
    $headers = array();
    foreach($_SERVER as $key => $value) {
        if (substr($key, 0, 5) <> 'HTTP_') {
            continue;
        }
        $header = str_replace(' ', '-', ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', strtolower(substr($key, 5)))));
        $headers[$header] = $value;
    }
    return $headers;
}

$headers = getRequestHeaders();

foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
    echo "$header: $value <br />\n";
}
```

**See Also**:
[getallheaders()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php) - (PHP >= 5.4) <s>cross platform edition</s> Alias of `apache_request_headers()` 
[apache_response_headers()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-response-headers.php) - Fetch all HTTP response headers.
[headers_list()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-list.php) - Fetch a list of headers to be sent.

Comment: I assume this is only when using the Apache server... might need to let the OP know that :)

Comment: I don't care about 82% of amateurs. I care about professional installations. No one in right state of mind would try to run high traffic site on mod_php.

Comment: @Jacco Yes, and I think that makes a perfect reason for downvoting. At any given time the best answer should be upvoted and bad answers downvoted. This is not a site of historical solutions :-)

Comment: @ThomasJensen Consider though, that some might be interessted in other or all headers and not esspecially in 'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'; The answere is absolute correct and Jacco explecitely stated that it only works for apache; That it in some scenarios not the best / most performant solution is no reason for a downvote IMO.

Comment: @Paranaix A: I don't know what you mean, I haven't criticized the extent of the answer and your reasoning is exactly why I started my answer by answering the specific question and then elaborated with more general knowledge and links for further information.
B: I still don't think you should encourage the use of apache_request_headers(). Newbies finding this question will start using it which is a shame IMO when better functions exist.

Comment: Although it says that getallheaders is allowed via FastCGI, what about PHP-FPM? It seems to say that the function is undefined

Comment: You only scan for uppercase HTML which is wrong, RFC2616 (HTTP/1.1) states headers are case insensitive, and not just the value part which you have covered.  The header name can be all lowercase too.

Comment: getallheaders() is not a cross-platform edition of `apache_request_headers()` - it's an alias thereof. Says so right in the linked manual page. I tested and the function is undefined on nginx.

Comment: PHP converts the http header name to uppercase and changes dashes to underscores. If you have a header called My-Custom-Header you have to read $_SERVER['HTTP_MY_CUSTOM_HEADER'];

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_XXXXXX_XXXX']` doesn't work for all headers. In fact it works only for a few of them.

Comment: Also, no only UPPERCASE, but convert dashes to underscores, too.

Comment: @BrunoCorrêaZimmermann Hi. Could you please extend your comment a bit? I'm trying to find a solution to read ALL **request** headers in PHP, without taking in consideration the web server type. That's why I'm asking you. Thank you!

Comment: @JurajPetrik: it certainly seems so, but for one, I couldn't find it written in the PHP docs (despite I kinda' vaguely remembered that I had read it somewhere there, but now googling didn't help). Could you please point to something "official"?

Comment: `getallheaders()` is since PHP 7.3 available via the FPM SAPI [too](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php#refsect1-function.getallheaders-changelog) and no longer restricted to Apache @tvanc

Comment: Still downvoted because @Thomas Jensen was right. Answered in 2009, the web get some improvements since. This answer should not be selected as the real answer actually.

Comment: So what is the correct answer to this in 2022?

Answer (score 390):

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']
```

[RFC3875](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3875.html), 4.1.18:

> Meta-variables with names beginning with `HTTP_` contain values read from the client request header fields, if the protocol used is HTTP. The HTTP header field name is converted to upper case, has all occurrences of `-` replaced with `_` and has `HTTP_` prepended to give the meta-variable name.

Comment: Can I reliably expect any server to put every header into the `$_SERVER` variable? The PHP documentation at http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php is evasive about what we can be sure will be in there.

Comment: This will not (always) work, especially in PHP-fpm (or cgi ).  This header is not always available from within PHP.

Comment: Using this solution I only see some of the request headers, and in this case, i don't see the one I want.  Chrome is sending a `cache-control` header, but I do not see it anywhere in `$_SERVER`.  I do see several headers prefixed with `HTTP_`, including "HTTP_ACCEPT", and "HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS" and "HTTP_USER_AGENT" (among several others).  But nothing for "cache-control" also nothing for "pragma".  This is regardless of case or  `HTTP_` prefix.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @EvandelaCruz: http://leserged.online.fr/phpinfo.php I see it here: `_SERVER["HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL"] max-age=0`

Comment: hmmm, thanks...  This is on my wamp dev server and I think PHP is running as an Apache module but I'm not sure.  Let me check on my prod box with FPM and see if I can figure out why I don't see it here on wamp...

Comment: @Quassnoi ok nevermind.  I am using chrome and I have the f12 dev tools open and I have the box checked that says "Disable cache".  And I triple-checked in that same dev tools window that the caching request headers were indeed being sent from the browser.  Chrome reported that they were being sent.  But the `$_SERVER` did not show them.  However, after reading your answer I checked my phpinfo.php and the headers were indeed there!  So, I went back to my debug script: `print_r($_SERVER);die();` and did a hard refresh (ctrl+f5) and sure enough, the caching headers are now showing.

Comment: @Quassnoi So either Chrome has a bug/undocumented feature, or I am starting to lose my mind in my old age and I didn't triple-check the request headers and/or I didn't have the dev tools open.  Should I delete my original comment as to not lend support to the wrong voice?  Or should I leave it here for accurate historical sake? Anyways thanks for showing me your phpinfo I would have outright doubted you otherwise... saved me some time chasing my tail

Comment: @EvandelaCruz: if you can reproduce it reliably, that would make a good question. The phpinfo is not mine, it's the first google hit on "phpinfo online"

Comment: @Quassnoi Looks like it is more likely my fault.  I think what happened was this (which is perhaps a UI oversight, but I wouldn't call it a "bug"): I opened dev tools (f12) and I clicked the "disable cache".  I refreshed the window and saw my debug output.  I then right-clicked the page and clicked "view-source", which opened another tab with the source code (it is formatted better in source view since I didn't wrap the output in a `<pre>` and the array is output with newlines, not HTML). Well, the tab that opened did *not* have the dev tools open.  And so presumably, it did not send the...

Comment: ...caching request headers.  And so, $_SERVER told the truth it seems.  So the issue may be that modern browsers reload the page when showing the source code view (although there are reasons for that too), or that Chrome should have maintained the dev-tools-state when showing the source view.  Anyways I'm way off topic now I suppose but I wanted to offer a conclusion.

Comment: This is way clearer to me than the explanation accepted by OP (even if the solution is the same), and plus, it has an example, it should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 61):

You should find all HTTP headers in the `$_SERVER` global variable prefixed with `HTTP_` uppercased and with dashes (-) replaced by underscores (_).

For instance your `X-Requested-With` can be found in:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']
```

It might be convenient to create an associative array from the `$_SERVER` variable. This can be done in several styles, but here's a function that outputs camelcased keys:

```
$headers = array();
foreach ($_SERVER as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, 'HTTP_') === 0) {
        $headers[str_replace(' ', '', ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', strtolower(substr($key, 5)))))] = $value;
    }
}
```

Now just use `$headers['XRequestedWith']` to retrieve the desired header.

PHP manual on `$_SERVER`: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: The best answer, in my opinion, is Thomas's explanation with Quassnoi's end result.  An associative array is usually not what's needed, and it isn't very easy to work out the simple solution from reading the `parseRequestHeaders()` function.  If such an associative array is needed, then IMO the apache function is the best option, since it returns exactly the headers received instead of a mangled CamelCase version.  (Also note that as of PHP 5.4, it is no longer Apache-only.)

Comment: Would you have answered this 2 years and 11 months faster, this answer would have 200+ upvotes.

Comment: `apache_request_headers()` or `getallheaders()` doesn't seem to capitalize the Header names when I tested. They are returning exactly as I pass from client side. Then why are you capitalizing header names in such a replacement function?

Answer (score 39):

Since PHP 5.4.0 you can use [`getallheaders`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php) function which returns all request headers as an associative array:

```
var_dump(getallheaders());

// array(8) {
//   ["Accept"]=>
//   string(63) "text/html[...]"
//   ["Accept-Charset"]=>
//   string(31) "ISSO-8859-1[...]"
//   ["Accept-Encoding"]=>
//   string(17) "gzip,deflate,sdch"
//   ["Accept-Language"]=>
//   string(14) "en-US,en;q=0.8"
//   ["Cache-Control"]=>
//   string(9) "max-age=0"
//   ["Connection"]=>
//   string(10) "keep-alive"
//   ["Host"]=>
//   string(9) "localhost"
//   ["User-Agent"]=>
//   string(108) "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) [...]"
// }
```

Earlier this function worked only when PHP was running as an Apache/NSAPI module.

Comment: I'm using it on PHP-FPM 5.5 and NGINX. getallheaders() does not exist.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai in FPM how you got the header information?

Comment: TLFTP; If you are using FPM `getallheaders()` became available after 7.3

Answer (score 7):

Pass a header name to this function to get its value without using `for` loop. Returns null if header not found.

```
/**
 * @var string $headerName case insensitive header name
 *
 * @return string|null header value or null if not found
 */
function get_header($headerName)
{
    $headers = getallheaders();
    return isset($headerName) ? $headers[$headerName] : null;
}
```

*Note: this works only with Apache server, see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php*

*Note: this function will process and load all of the headers to the memory and it's less performant than a `for` loop.*

Answer (score 6):

`strtolower` is lacking in several of the proposed solutions, RFC2616 (HTTP/1.1) defines header fields as case-insensitive entities.  The whole thing, not just the **value** part.

So suggestions like only parsing *HTTP_* entries are wrong.

Better would be like this:

```
if (!function_exists('getallheaders')) {
    foreach ($_SERVER as $name => $value) {
        /* RFC2616 (HTTP/1.1) defines header fields as case-insensitive entities. */
        if (strtolower(substr($name, 0, 5)) == 'http_') {
            $headers[str_replace(' ', '-', ucwords(strtolower(str_replace('_', ' ', substr($name, 5)))))] = $value;
        }
    }
    $this->request_headers = $headers;
} else {
    $this->request_headers = getallheaders();
}
```

Notice the subtle differences with previous suggestions.  The function here also works on php-fpm (+nginx).

Comment: Where exactly does RFC 2616 state that field values are case-insensitive? It explitly states that "HTTP-date is case sensitive" — and that goes into `Date` header — and that "Parameter values [text in Content-Type after semicolon] might or might not be case-sensitive". So given there are at least two headers with case-sensitive values, it seems that you're wrong.

Comment: ```HTTP header fields, which include general-header (section 4.5),
   request-header (section 5.3), response-header (section 6.2), and
   entity-header (section 7.1) fields, follow the same generic format as
   that given in Section 3.1 of RFC 822 [9]. Each header field consists
   of a name followed by a colon (":") and the field value. Field names
   are case-insensitive.```   So I guess you're wrong.

Comment: Field *names* are case-insensitive. There is nothing about field *values* in this paragraph, while other parts of the document explicitly tell about case-sensitive field values.

Comment: Why ya all replacing underline to space then space to dash? wouldn't this just work:  $headers[ucwords(strtolower(substr($name, 5)))] = $value; ?

Answer (score 6):

I was using CodeIgniter and used the code below to get it. May be useful for someone in future.

```
$this->input->get_request_header('X-Requested-With');
```

Comment: It was. Knew about get_request_header() method though, but wasn't sure I could use the header name as is, i.e. without having to change hyphens to underscores.

Answer (score 6):

if only one key is required to retrieved, For example `"Host"` address is required, then we can use

```
apache_request_headers()['Host']
```

So that we can avoid loops and put it inline to the echo outputs

Comment: Starting with PHP 5.4. In 5.3, this syntax will cause an error.

Comment: this is tested with PHP 7.1

Comment: you run PHP as an Apache module or, as of PHP 5.4, using FastCGI (simple method):

apache_request_headers() as mentioned below

Answer (score 4):

To make things simple, here is how you can get just the one you want:

Simple:

```
$headerValue = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'];
```

or when you need to get one at a time:

```
<?php
/**
 * @param $pHeaderKey
 * @return mixed
 */
function get_header( $pHeaderKey )
{
    // Expanded for clarity.
    $headerKey = str_replace('-', '_', $pHeaderKey);
    $headerKey = strtoupper($headerKey);
    $headerValue = NULL;
    // Uncomment the if when you do not want to throw an undefined index error.
    // I leave it out because I like my app to tell me when it can't find something I expect.
    //if ( array_key_exists($headerKey, $_SERVER) ) {
    $headerValue = $_SERVER[ $headerKey ];
    //}
    return $headerValue;
}
// X-Requested-With mainly used to identify Ajax requests. Most JavaScript frameworks
// send this header with value of XMLHttpRequest, so this will not always be present.
$header_x_requested_with = get_header( 'X-Requested-With' );
```

The other headers are also in the super global array $_SERVER, you can read about how to get at them here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Comparing to other answers it seems that you function will not work as it does not prepend `HTTP_` to the `$headerKey`

Answer (score 2):

This work if you have an Apache server

PHP Code:

```
$headers = apache_request_headers();

foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
    echo "$header: $value <br />\n";
}
```

Result:

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0
Host: www.example.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'm doing it. You need to get all headers if $header_name isn't passed:

```
<?php
function getHeaders($header_name=null)
{
    $keys=array_keys($_SERVER);

    if(is_null($header_name)) {
            $headers=preg_grep("/^HTTP_(.*)/si", $keys);
    } else {
            $header_name_safe=str_replace("-", "_", strtoupper(preg_quote($header_name)));
            $headers=preg_grep("/^HTTP_${header_name_safe}$/si", $keys);
    }

    foreach($headers as $header) {
            if(is_null($header_name)){
                    $headervals[substr($header, 5)]=$_SERVER[$header];
            } else {
                    return $_SERVER[$header];
            }
    }

    return $headervals;
}
print_r(getHeaders());
echo "\n\n".getHeaders("Accept-Language");
?>
```

It looks a lot simpler to me than most of the examples given in other answers.  This also gets the method (GET/POST/etc.) and the URI requested when getting all of the headers which can be useful if you're trying to use it in logging.

Here's the output:

```
Array ( [HOST] => 127.0.0.1 [USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0 [ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 [ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-US,en;q=0.5 [ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate [COOKIE] => PHPSESSID=MySessionCookieHere [CONNECTION] => keep-alive )

en-US,en;q=0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way to do it.

```
// echo get_header('X-Requested-With');
function get_header($field) {
    $headers = headers_list();
    foreach ($headers as $header) {
        list($key, $value) = preg_split('/:\s*/', $header);
        if ($key == $field)
            return $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that headers that get sent out?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai No. "headers_list() will return a list of headers to be sent to the browser/client" - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-list.php

Comment: @OpeyemiObembe so yes.

Comment: Yea. That's what I meant.

Comment: @MivhaelLeaney Yes - headers to be sent TO the client, i.e incoming headers, not headers to be sent out from the client.

Comment: The question is asking for headers sent to the server. They are the request headers.

Comment: The source and destination, when using terms like "sent",  "out", "to", "from", is relative to the context in which those terms are used.  In this answer, the example shows PHP running on the *server*.  And, the OP's question also referenced server-side PHP.  Therefore, @CMCDragonkai and MichaelLeany are correct.  This is a bad answer.  "sent out", in this context, means "HTTP response headers sent from the server".  kehers is commenting from the point-of-view of the client, but both his answer and the OP's question are from the point of view of the server.

Answer (score 0):

This small PHP snippet can be helpful to you:

```
<?php
foreach($_SERVER as $key => $value){
echo '$_SERVER["'.$key.'"] = '.$value."<br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: Simpler: `var_export($_SERVER);` .

Answer (score 0):

```
function getCustomHeaders()
{
    $headers = array();
    foreach($_SERVER as $key => $value)
    {
        if(preg_match("/^HTTP_X_/", $key))
            $headers[$key] = $value;
    }
    return $headers;
}
```

I use this function to get the custom headers, if the header starts from "HTTP_X_" we push in the array :)

Answer (score 0):

PHP 7: Null Coalesce Operator

```
//$http = 'SCRIPT_NAME';
$http = 'X_REQUESTED_WITH';
$http = strtoupper($http);
$header = $_SERVER['HTTP_'.$http] ?? $_SERVER[$http] ?? NULL;

if(is_null($header)){
    die($http. ' Not Found');
}
echo $header;
```

Answer (score -2):

Below code works for me to get any specific data submitted in the header

```
foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
   if($name=='Authorization') //here you can search by name
   $Authorization= $value ;
}
```

Comment: That's a horribly inefficient approach compared to all the other answers using `getallheaders`

Comment: on top of which, the indentation (and lack of braces) makes it that easy to cause mistakes...