# WebClient Upload file with variables posted

Tags: c#, webclient

I am using the code below to upload a file to a remote php page.  I would like to post an additional variable to verify the identity of the system uploading the file.  Is there any way to add a header to the WebClient UploadFile that would allow the receiving script to have access to a posted variable?

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.UploadFileAsync(new Uri(HTTP_VERSIONCTRL_URL), fileloc);
webClient.UploadProgressChanged += OnProgress;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a header like this

```
webClient.Headers.Add("OurSecurityHeader", "encryptedvalue");
```

On the php side, you can use this to read headers:

[How do I read any request header in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541430/how-do-i-read-any-request-header-in-php)