# Getting/Setting request property in HTTP request Android

Tags: php, android, http-headers

I am setting some key value pair at client side in android, how can i get it at server side.

code:

```
               FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
               URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

               // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
               HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
               conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
               conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
               conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
               conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
               conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
               conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 

               conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);
               conn.setRequestProperty("key_1", "value_1"); 
               conn.setRequestProperty("key_2", "value?_2"); 
               conn.setRequestProperty("key_3", "value_3"); 

               conn.setRequestProperty("key_n", "value_n");
```

**how can get key_1,key_2 .... key_n in php.**

i have tried all these way

```
$_GET['key_1'];
$_REQUEST['key_1'];
$_POST['key_1'];
$_FILE['key_1'];
```

all of these are not working for me,

please guys help me.

Comment: You did not really write `['key']` did you?

Comment: Try to write ['key_1'] 2, 3, n

Comment: means i was written key_1,_key... key_n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

these are headers, not post or get values.
you may need to read them from $_SERVER['']

or check this post too
[How do I read any request header in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541430/how-do-i-read-any-request-header-in-php)