# PHP - How can i access a variable passing through header request

Tags: php

I have a requirement to access a sessionID variable passed through header. I need to verify the sessionID before process the request. Also please let us know how can i set a sessionID in request header. please help me to find a solution. Your help is much appreciated. Thank you

[image]

I have tried

```
$headers = apache_request_headers();

foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
    echo "$header: $value <br />\n";
}
```

Comment: Have you had a look at `print_r($_SERVER)`?

Comment: [session_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I read any request header in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541430/how-do-i-read-any-request-header-in-php)

Comment: @deceze I have tried its printing all header parameters. Do you know how to set a header variable in php?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
    echo "$name: $value\n";
}
```

This will give all the information of header.

Here is more tutorial about [getallheaders()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php) function.

If you want to get only session id then use the below code:

```
echo session_id();
```

Answer (score 0):

To set a session you can use, 
session_start();

you can use GET method in 1st page to pass the id in header.
session_id($_GET['PHPSESSID']);
session_start();

You can extract the session id in another page by using session_id()
session_id() returns the session id for the current session 
else it retuns the empty string, if there is no current session.

```
    <?php
    $id = session_id();
    if(empty($id)) session_start();
    echo "SID: ".SID."<br>session_id(): ".session_id()."<br>COOKIE: ".$_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"];
    ?>
```

Hope This helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but my requirement is to pass that session_id via header request and take it in another php page and verify.

Comment: you can use GET method in 1st page to pass the id in header.

You can extract the session id in another page by using session_id()