# Return file contents with Content-type from Javascript

Tags: javascript, content-type

I'm trying to include a vCard in a Weebly website, but I need to return the Content-type header, so a simple attachment won't work. I have found the following code in PHP to do this, but I can't include PHP code on Weebly, only Javascript:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/x-vcard");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"contact.vcf\";");
    echo file_get_contents("contact.vcf");
?>
```

Is there a way to include a button that would return this in Javascript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541430/how-do-i-read-any-request-header-in-php may help

Comment: @BipBip OP is asking about a Javascript solution. How does another PHP question help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add this in a simple anchor tag and the browsers will handle it.

```
<a href="contact.vcf">My Contact</a>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm doing it all wrong, but according to [this website](http://learnyii.blogspot.com.br/2011/04/vcard-qr-code-iphone-android-blackberry.html): "Blackberry can't read vCards directly from a QR Code, but you can qr-code a URL that returns a vCard. You'll want to send back this PHP header: header("Content-type:text/x-vcard");" Is just the `href=` enough for that?

Comment: I don't know, can you test it?