# Laravel 4 app (behind haproxy) Request::header() giving response headers?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, http-headers, haproxy

When I do a GET request for a url on my laravel web app, I do the following in my controller to retrieve a custom header:

```
Request::header('customheader');
```

This value is always blank, though the header is clearly visible in Chrome Developer Tools in the `Request Headers`

While troubleshooting I tried using a standard header: `Connection`

Looking at the request headers, I expected the following:

```
Request::header('Connection') == "keep-alive"
```

What is super weird is that this instead returned `"close"` aka, the value of `Connection` in the `Response Headers`. This explains why my custom header is showing up empty (it is not in the response, but the request).

So what gives? The Laravel docs clearly state that this is the way to retreive REQUEST headers.

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#request-information

Any soltuions to get what I want?

edit: `$_SERVER["HTTP_HEADER_NAME"]` as proposed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/541450/1800023 gives me the same results. The values are those from the RESPONSE headers.

Comment: How are you getting Chrome to send over custom headers?

Comment: I am just doing an ajax request with a custom header in the `headers:` field.

Comment: if it helps, my laravel server is behind an haproxy setup

Comment: have you `wireshark` any request from HAProxy to your Web Server? i suspect it had something to do with it.

Comment: i haven't, and the guy that would be the one to do that doesn't want to >_<