# php - how to read Request Header values

Tags: php

I'm coding for a someone , he told me that he will send two parameters by the name of X_PAY_AMOUNT and X_PAY_MOBILE via Request Header .

The question is , How can I read these values when the page is calling ?

Comment: `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST`

Comment: to catch all http request header you can use `getallheaders()`

Comment: Possible this question is duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541430/how-do-i-read-any-request-header-in-php