# Get Ajax Header Information in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm making an ajax function for uploading files (video or image) like this :

```
function upload_file(file)
     {
        //create xhr object
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        //initiate request
        xhr.open('post','hisoka_drop.php',true);//true for asynchronous

        //set headers
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type',"multipart/form-data");
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Name',file.fileName);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Size',file.fileSize);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Type',file.fileType);

        //send the file
        xhr.send(file);

     }
```

And in my hisoka_drop.php :

```
<?php
    $str =file_get_contents('php://input');
    $filename = ; //How to get ajax header about file.fileName;
    $path = 'upload/'.$filename;
    file_put_contents($path,$str);
    echo $path;
    ?>
```

My question is simple, how do I get the ajax header that I have set before in order to get the real filename of the file that I want to upload to server...
Thanks in advance... :)

NOTE:
I have tried to list all headers in $_SERVER as shown below :

```
Key ==>MIBDIRS
 Value ==>C:/xampp/php/extras/mibs
 Key ==>MYSQL_HOME
 Value ==>\xampp\mysql\bin
 Key ==>OPENSSL_CONF
 Value ==>C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf
 Key ==>PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR
 Value ==>\xampp\php
 Key ==>PHPRC
 Value ==>\xampp\php
 Key ==>TMP
 Value ==>\xampp\tmp
 Key ==>HTTP_HOST
 Value ==>localhost:8080
 Key ==>HTTP_CONNECTION
 Value ==>keep-alive
 Key ==>CONTENT_LENGTH
 Value ==>305658
 Key ==>HTTP_ORIGIN
 Value ==>http://localhost:8080
 Key ==>HTTP_USER_AGENT
 Value ==>Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36
 Key ==>CONTENT_TYPE
 Value ==>multipart/form-data
 Key ==>HTTP_ACCEPT
 Value ==>*/*
 Key ==>HTTP_DNT
 Value ==>1
 Key ==>HTTP_REFERER
 Value ==>http://localhost:8080/task3/
 Key ==>HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING
 Value ==>gzip, deflate
 Key ==>HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE
 Value ==>en-US,en;q=0.8,id;q=0.6
 Key ==>HTTP_COOKIE
 Value ==>PHPSESSID=crk3e9v9m4ri6k2nn8snhihu67
 Key ==>PATH
 Value ==>C:\Python33\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;
 Key ==>SystemRoot
 Value ==>C:\Windows
 Key ==>COMSPEC
 Value ==>C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
 Key ==>PATHEXT
 Value ==>.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
 Key ==>WINDIR
 Value ==>C:\Windows
 Key ==>SERVER_SIGNATURE
 Value ==><address>Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1l PHP/5.5.24 Server at localhost Port 8080</address>

 Key ==>SERVER_SOFTWARE
 Value ==>Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1l PHP/5.5.24
 Key ==>SERVER_NAME
 Value ==>localhost
 Key ==>SERVER_ADDR
 Value ==>::1
 Key ==>SERVER_PORT
 Value ==>8080
 Key ==>REMOTE_ADDR
 Value ==>::1
 Key ==>DOCUMENT_ROOT
 Value ==>C:/xampp/htdocs
 Key ==>REQUEST_SCHEME
 Value ==>http
 Key ==>CONTEXT_PREFIX
 Value ==>
 Key ==>CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT
 Value ==>C:/xampp/htdocs
 Key ==>SERVER_ADMIN
 Value ==>postmaster@localhost
 Key ==>SCRIPT_FILENAME
 Value ==>C:/xampp/htdocs/task3/hisoka_drop.php
 Key ==>REMOTE_PORT
 Value ==>60706
 Key ==>GATEWAY_INTERFACE
 Value ==>CGI/1.1
 Key ==>SERVER_PROTOCOL
 Value ==>HTTP/1.1
 Key ==>REQUEST_METHOD
 Value ==>POST
 Key ==>QUERY_STRING
 Value ==>
 Key ==>REQUEST_URI
 Value ==>/task3/hisoka_drop.php
 Key ==>SCRIPT_NAME
 Value ==>/task3/hisoka_drop.php
 Key ==>PHP_SELF
 Value ==>/task3/hisoka_drop.php
 Key ==>REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT
 Value ==>1469489572.122
 Key ==>REQUEST_TIME
 Value ==>1469489572
 Key ==>REQUEST_TIME
```

And from this list, I couldn't find any header that I have sent, like FILE_NAME, FILE_SIZE, and FILE_TYPE, so what's is the problem here...??
Thanks in advance again..

Comment: there is simpler way to dump contents of array: `var_export($_SERVER)` or `var_dump($_SERVER)` or `print_r($_SERVER);` =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Also, as of 5.4.0 you can use `apache_request_headers()`. It returns all HTTP request headers from the current request as array.

In earlier versions this function works only if PHP installed as apache module.

Usage will look like this:

```
$headers = apache_request_headers();
echo $headers['X-File-Name'];
```

Comment: Sounds interesting, but how do I get just a specific header Mr. Spirit...? :)

Comment: like this: `$headers = apache_request_headers(); echo $headers['X-File-Name'];`

Comment: Thanks so much, I finally get my beautiful Header.... :)
I'm gonna put myOwn answer later... :)

Answer (score 5):

Since your custom HTTP header is called, `X-File-Name`, simply uppercase it, convert dashes to underscores, and prepend `HTTP_` to form the key you would use to find it in the `$_SERVER` superglobal. e.g.:

```
$filename = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME'];
```

For more info, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/541463/166339).

Comment: Thanks a loot Mr. Asaph... :)

Comment: I have updated my question Mr. Asaph, seem that $_SERVER doesn't bring any headers that I sent before..