# How to Read Retrofit Custom Header in PHP

Tags: php, android, retrofit2

for some reason i'm sending some custom header in my Service, this is my code :

```
@GET("categories")
Call<List<Category>> categoryList(@Header("userName") String userName);
```

i'm wondering how i can get the value of my custom header in my php code, all what i know is :

```
$headerStringValue = $_SERVER['HTTP_XXXXXX_XXXX'];
```

what is the key that i should use to get the right value ?

thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read any request header in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541430/how-do-i-read-any-request-header-in-php)