# Get headers values of Postman Google Chrome app with php

Tags: php, postman

How we get the postman google chrome headers values with PHP. Want to show the value of headers in PHP variable?

Comment: Use `HTTP_*` from [$_SERVER](http://php.net/reserved.variables.server) or use [getallheaders()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read any request header in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541430/how-do-i-read-any-request-header-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

If you are on an Apache web server you can use this php method: [apache-request-headers()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php).
This method returns an array with all incoming Request headers (coming from  Postman).

Example:

```
<?php
print_r( apache_request_headers() );
?>
```

Returns:

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0
Host: www.example.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
```