# how to get the header value, if we don't know the value because the value is random from the server

Tags: php, http-headers

For example: header name "alphabet"

```
alphabet: abcde
```

next request the value changes from the server

```
alphabet: jkfrts
```

and then continue to     change

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
$value = $_SERVER['HTTP_ALPHABET'];
//notice the pattern and the conversion to uppercase $_SERVER['HTTP_XXXXXX_XXXX'];
```

[more on this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/541450/5407848)

Comment: Undefined index: HTTP_ALPHABET

Comment: Then, there is no header with the name `alphabet`

Answer (score 0):

0){ echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "
"; }else{ echo getcwd().'
'; echo "Upload in file named: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "
"; $info = pathinfo($_FILES['userFile']['name']); $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION); $target = 'upload/100.'.$ext; move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target); } ?>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).