# How to get headers from incoming php request

Tags: php, header

I'm trying to get headers (*authorization* row from headers) from incoming php request (php://input) but can't get it.

i'm trying that:

```
get_headers('php://input');
```

but i had error

```
get_headers(): This function may only be used against URLs in /path..
```

Comment: This should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541430/how-do-i-read-any-request-header-in-php

Comment: @DrOpossum, nah... i already read this... but... $_SERVER can get  *local* data... not for incoming headers

Comment: `$_SERVER` can be used to get request headers passed to the webserer (and therefore PHP). You could use this to access the Authorization Header. Isn't that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

with PHP 7.3 the function `getallheaders()` can [now](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php#refsect1-function.getallheaders-changelog) be used in a (nginx) php-fpm context too and is no longer restricted to Apache only, so for most users this is an easy pick if they are on >= 7.3. A [polyfill](https://github.com/ralouphie/getallheaders) exists that uses the `$_SERVER` global if you cannot upgrade to PHP 7.3 yet that is similar to what is proposed in the answer linked in the comments. (beware of case-sensitiveness though)

```
$headers = getallheaders();
echo $headers['Authorization'];
```