# Header sent from Java changes it name on PHP side

Tags: java, php, nginx

I am sending `X-Auth-HMAC` header from Java using HttpClient to Nginx + PHP-FPM combo:

```
        HttpClient
                .newBuilder()
                .build()
                .sendAsync(
                        HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                                .uri("php-fpm:80")
                                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                                .header("X-Auth-HMAC", "test_hmac_header")
                                .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString("test_body"))
                                .build(),
                        HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString()
                );
```

But on PHP side in `$_SERVER` variable among all headers i get:

```
  ...
 "HTTP_X_AUTH_HMAC":"test_hmac_header",
 ...
```

How could `X-Auth-HMAC` become `HTTP_X_AUTH_HMAC` ?

Comment: Looks a bit like constant variable name would have been accidentally added in quotes and set as header name instead of the constant value....

Comment: In `$_SERVER` HTTP headers are formatted according to RFC 3875. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541430/how-do-i-read-any-request-header-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP formats HTTP headers in the `$_SERVER` variable according to [RFC 3875](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3875.html) (the CGI 1.1 spec).

Specifically section 4.1.18:

> Meta-variables with names beginning with HTTP_ contain values read
> from the client request header fields, if the protocol used is HTTP.
> The HTTP header field name is converted to upper case, has all
> occurrences of - replaced with _ and has HTTP_ prepended to give the
> meta-variable name.

Take a loot at this answer for more discussion and alternate methods of getting HTTP headers: [How do I read any request header in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541430/how-do-i-read-any-request-header-in-php)