# How to access values in a POST Request header in php

Tags: php, post, request, header

I am new to php and trying to integrate a payment system. After a successful bank transfer, a POST request is sent to my webhook. I am supposed to compute a hashed value and then compare it with a value in the request header before honouring the request.

My endpoint receives the request and i have been able to retrieve the request body as well as compute the required hash. However, i do not know how to compare my value with the value sent in the request header. How do I access the named value from the request HEADER? Thanks in advance for your help[Screenshot of the Instruction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hb8XO.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read any request header in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541430/how-do-i-read-any-request-header-in-php)

Answer (score -2):

Try `$_SERVER['HTTP_MONNIFY_SIGNATURE'];`

Comment: It still did not work