# How to get Header & data-raw Of Curl Response from PHP

Tags: php, curl, callback, postback

Using third party service; they are providing webhook services; I have given my url to send the response on my page:
Example: https://abcd.com/postback.php

Getting curl response on postback.php; to read the POST data; I am using following code:

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

but not able to read the header & data content.

Sample Response that they are sending:

```
curl -L -X POST 'https://abcd.com/postback.php' -H 'x-changenow-signature: xcgh123POPI6727kslsldjsd' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{"status":"finished","payinHash":"31mrEanXyv","payoutHash":"485d8dz","payinAddress":"3Nups0bF","payoutAddress":"1K1LcQSPZVj2dM","fromCurrency":"sol","toCurrency":"btc","amountSend":0.06676453,"amountReceive":0.00010273,"refundAddress":"Bk1qVzc3GULcJQ0NoW4DsepRJHevzAD8ynznEQ1aNzGq","id":"f7bed8a9e4a350","updatedAt":"2022-06-23T11:22:38.728Z","createdAt":"2022-06-23T11:09:56.403Z","expectedReceiveAmount":0.0001024,"isPartner":false}
```

Please suggest how to get header and data part.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read any request header in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541430/how-do-i-read-any-request-header-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

The headers are in `$_SERVER`. Use `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_CHANGENOW_SIGNATURE']` to get the `x-changenow-signature` header.

The data content is in `$postdata`. Use

```
$data = json_decode($postdata);
```

to convert it to an object. Then you can use `$data->status`, `$data->payinHash`, etc. to get the fields of the post data.