# CORS blocking allowed headers

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, axios, cors

Hello I have created an API and front end using React and doing request with axios.
I added an authorization header with axios and I authorized it with php server-side but when the browser send the POST request, there is no Authorization Header.

// Tasks.js

```
const httpClient = axios.create({baseURL: "http://localhost/cpp/api/v1/"})
const resp = await httpClient.post("/work/createWork.php", {
    body: {
        taskid: id,
        title: data.name,
        content: data.content,
        date: data.date,
        matiere: data.matiere,
        userID: 3
    },
    headers: {
        'Authorization': "XXXXXXXX"
    }
});
```

// createWork.php

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Header: Content-Type, Authorization");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400");

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'OPTIONS') {
    http_response_code(204);
    exit;
}

include './../main.php';

global $db;

$rq = new APIRequest("POST", true);

header("Content-Type: application/json");

if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_Authorization'])) {
    echo "{\"error\": \"This endpoint need auth.\"}";
    http_response_code(403);
    return;
}
```

ERROR : `POST http://localhost/cpp/api/v1/work/createWork.php [HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden 19ms]`

Comment: The client is sending the header `Authorization`, but the server is checking for the header `HTTP_Authorization`.

Comment: @outlaw It looks to be the correct way: [How do I read any request header in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/541463/2257664). But it should be in uppercase though.

Comment: @A.L whoops, thanks! I always use `getallheaders()` and didn't realize they were stored in `$_SERVER` with the prepended `http`!

Comment: For one thing, your code contains a typo: `Access-Control-Allow-Header` should be `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` (plural). This is one reason why I recommend the use of an existing CORS middleware library rather than that of a middleware written from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### JS

The [Axios documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example) shows that headers are provided as the third parameter of the `post` method (indentation added so that's it's easier to see):

```js
const {data} = await axios.post(
    '/user',
    document.querySelector('#my-form'),
    {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }
)
```

So you have to remove `headers` that is next to `body` and pass it as the third parameter:

```js
const httpClient = axios.create({baseURL: "http://localhost/cpp/api/v1/"})
const resp = await httpClient.post(
    "/work/createWork.php",
    {
        taskid: id,
        title: data.name,
        content: data.content,
        date: data.date,
        matiere: data.matiere,
        userID: 3
    },
    {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': "79619bca-225b-4f28-b337-43d37bbb5048"
        }
    },
);
```

The `body` isn't shown in the documentation, I removed it.

### PHP

```php
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_Authorization'])) {
```

should be:

```php
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'])) {
```

See [How do I read any request header in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/541450/2257664).

Comment: Thank you I’ll test it when I will be home.

Comment: I applied your modification and it's always the same error (403) but this time, the header has been sended

Comment: @PastaLaPate you can dump the content of `$_SERVER` to see what is happening, with something like `var_dump($_SERVER);`.

Comment: Yes and in $_SERVER the header is not present

Comment: I can't explain why the header is sent by the browser but not received by the PHP side. Please edit the question if something is missing, like a proxy that could intercept the headers.

Comment: I think I am going to use ``getallHeaders()``